# bash string to date

Tags: bash, datetime, formatting

Is there an opportunity to convert a string into a date in bash? For example: I have a time format: `"%Y-%m-%dS%H:%M:%S"`. An example of such string is `"2009-06-24S12:34:56"`. I need to convert this string into a date (unix timestamp) in bash. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "date"? Do you mean a UNIX timestamp? Or some other date format?

Answer (score 15):

Use

```
date --utc --date "<input string>" +%s
```

Comment: I am on solaris 10. This does not work on it. Sorry, I should have mentioned the OS.
date: illegal option -- utc
date: illegal option -- date
usage:  date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff]

Comment: Ah, Solaris. If you do a quick Google search you'll find a lot of people struggling with the same problem: Solaris' date program isn't nearly as powerful as the others out there. You could probably get the same results using Perl or a C program though.

Comment: And Perl should also be available on almost any Solaris box.

Comment: Also not applicable for OSX