# Parsing string for retrieving date in bash

Tags: bash

I have s string in following format `dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss`(e.g `13/Jan/2011:08:23:34`) I need to convert this string to date. How can I do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253828/bash-string-to-date

Comment: I tried date -d "13/Jan/2011:08:23:34" but it doesn't work. It says invalid date

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

GNU Date

```
mydate='13/Jan/2011:08:23:34'
date +%s -d "${mydate:3:3} ${mydate%%/*} ${mydate:7:4} ${mydate#*:}"
```

FreeBSD Date

```
mydate='13/Jan/2011:08:23:34'
date -j -f '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S' "${mydate}" +%s
```

Basically, with GNU date you must reformat your date into something GNU date can understand and parse. I chose a crude method (in the real world it would need to be more reliable). FreeBSD is better in this regard and allows you to specify the date format the parser should look for.

Answer (score 1):

You have to massage the date string to be valid for the `date` command.

Given `d="13/Jan/2011:08:23:34"`

1. `epoch=$( IFS="/:"; set -- $d; date -d "$1 $2 $3 $4:$5:$6" +%s )`
2. `d2=${d//\// } # replace slashes with spaces

   epoch=$( date -d "${d2/:/ }" +%s )`